# Find Argv[i] in /bin and /sbin in C

Tags: c, package-managers

I cannot locate `argv[i]` in `/bin` (or `/sbin`), package only checks the directory it was run from. How do I check for `argv[i]` in `/bin` and `/sbin`?

I am currently working on my own package manager and I am writing it in pure C. I am currently writing the check to see if the package(s) passed (using `argv[]`) are already installed. The issue I am having is that when I run for the check my code only checks in the directory it was run from and I need it to check `/bin` and `/sbin` (I am going to handle to checking of `/sbin`) and I am trying to get it to check `/bin`, but am having zero luck. I cannot seem to get this to work, each time they just check the current working directory and I need them to check `/bin`. I can't figure this out, has anyone by chance done this in pure C before? Thank you

These are all the methods I have tried so far, none of them work...

#### using stat()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        struct dirent *de = calloc(1, sizeof(struct dirent));
        DIR *dr = opendir("/bin"); /* directory to open */

        short i;
        struct stat *program = calloc(1, sizeof(struct stat));

        if (dr == NULL) {
                printf("directory could not be opened");
                return 0;
        }

        while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {
                for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {

                        if (stat(argv[i], program) == 0) {
                                printf("found\n");
                                closedir(dr);
                        }

                        else {
                                printf("not found\n");
                                closedir(dr);
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

#### using realpath

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        struct dirent *de = calloc(1, sizeof(struct dirent));
        DIR *dr = opendir("/bin"); /* directory to open */

        short i;
        char *res = realpath(argv[i], NULL);

        if (dr == NULL) {
                printf("directory could not be opened");
                return 0;
        }

        while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {
                for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {

                        if (res == NULL) {
                                printf("found\n");
                                closedir(dr);
                        }

                        else {
                                printf("not found\n");
                                closedir(dr);
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

#### using strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        struct dirent *de;
        DIR *dr = opendir("/bin"); /* directory to open */

        short i;
        struct stat program;

        if (dr == NULL) {
                printf("directory could not be opened");
                return 0;
        }

        while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {
                for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {

                        if (strcmp(de->d_name, argv[i]) == 0) {
                                printf("found\n");
                                closedir(dr);
                        }

                        else {
                                printf("not found\n");
                                closedir(dr);
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

I am expecting them all to work as follows:

```
check echo 

// it would go to /bin and find echo and then print
found
```

but when I run them they only check the current working directory, so for example:

```
check connection.c

// finds connection.c in the same directory
found
```

## Solution

Naha! I found a way to do it! So using the function `chdir()` I can run `stat()` in `/bin` like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        short i;
        struct stat *program = calloc(1, sizeof(struct stat));

        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
                chdir("/bin"); /* move to /bin */

                if (chdir("/bin") != 0)
                        return 1;

                if (stat(argv[i], program) == 0)
                        return 0;


                else
                        return 1;
                }
}
```

Comment: You could just build absolute paths and check with stat.

Comment: Why not just create an array of pointers to string literals for the prefix for the paths you want to check, e.g. `char *chkpaths[] = { "/bin", "/sbin", ... };` and then just loop over each of the pointers forming the path to check with `sprintf` and then call `stat`, (or for checking existence `access()` is fine)

Answer (score 0):

I tried simplifying your code just to output the contents of the folder,  I get the contents of the '/bin' folder each time.

As a general rule of thumb,  I like to get my code to compile without warnings,  test it does what I expect it to, then work on the next bit.

The 'struct stat program' was causing the code not to compile,  my guess is you were running an old version of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        struct dirent *de;
        DIR *dr = opendir("/bin"); /* directory to open */

        short i;
    //        struct stat program;

        if (dr == NULL) {
                printf("directory could not be opened");
                return 0;
        }

        while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {
      printf(de->d_name);
      printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: I did have a version that printed the contents of `/bin`, but I couldn't get it to check for argv[i] from what was printed. I have been stuck on this for weeks now and just feel lost and a little hopeless, I don't know how to get it to check. I keep reading the man pages and trying everything I can and nothing works.

Comment: I just wanted to update this and say that I was able to solve this issue and severally minimize my code base (which makes me happy) using `chdir`. The full solution is above, thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you’re confusing the semantics of `opendir`/`readdir` with those of [`chdir`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/chdir):

`opendir` does not change the working directory. This means that, e.g. `realpath("echo", resolved_path)` won’t resolve `echo` as `/bin/echo` but as `$PWD/echo` (where `$PWD` is the environment variable holding your current working directory).

That said, *as a general rule* you should not `chdir` inside your process. Instead, you can construct the path explicitly … e.g. via `sprintf`:

```
const char *binpath = "/bin";
char *fullpath = malloc(strlen(binpath) + 1 + strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
sprintf(fullpath, "%s/%s", binpath, argv[1]);
```

… and then `stat` the result (no need to dynamically allocate your `struct stat` either):

```
struct stat st;
if (stat(fullpath, &st) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error in stat(): %s", strerror(errno));
}

printf("%s has inode %ju\n", fullpath, (unsigned long) st.st_ino);
```